# Camel netty consumer not listen

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a problem setting up `camel` `netty` consumer for `514` port in order to catch `syslog` messages.
My `route`:

```
from("netty:udp://127.0.0.1:514?sync=false")
    .process(new Processor(){
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            processor.processAntyMalwareLog(exchange);
        }
    }).log("I've got message");
```

application is starting:

```
Route: route3 started and consuming from: Endpoint[udp://127.0.0.1:514]
```

and `514` port is opened but not is not listening

```
>netstat -lnp | grep 514
udp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:514         :::*                                21513/java
```

I can see in `tcpdump` with `tcpdump -i eth1 -nn -A -s 0 port 514 and udp` that the messages are are being send and received properly.

Can anyone point me where I am doing mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the client mode, eg set `clientMode=true`. See more details in the netty docs:

- http://camel.apache.org/netty.html

And upgrade and use Netty 4 if possible:

- http://camel.apache.org/netty4.html

Comment: It worked, I forgot to change to `netty4:udp` :) thank You very much ~!